# Helped in Chat to solve the problem

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I helped a guy to solve his issue in Chat and finally he got the answer for his question.

Also it was a 60 - 40 hard work, starting from my side respectively.

So what do you guys think whether I am eligible for any reputations for this.

Should I post an answer for the problem that he was facing so that question has an answer or should I tell him to post an answer himself.

Thanks.

Comment: Ask a (self) answered question regarding that problem, and let the community decide if it's useful and deserves giving you reputation.

Comment: Why ask another question when one already exists? It would just be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @TravisJ:  I'm not sure a question exists necessarily.  The impetus may be that this person asked their question in chat and was answered in chat, as opposed to linking a question from the main site and asking for an answer.

Comment: @Makoto - Well that is not what happened.

Comment: @TravisJ:  This is me speaking more as an outsider and, in all honesty, not convinced that a user who helps another person in chat deserves anything more than a pat on the back and a nice, long break.  If you have the actual question/answer thread in tow, that'd be nice to see for context.

Comment: @Makoto - I was in the middle of posting it when you replied here at first, you can see it below with reference.

Comment: Chat is a thankless place sometimes @Makoto ;)

Comment: If I post an answer will it not be helpful to the community and remove a question from unanswered list.

Comment: I would simply not invest that amount of energy unless op shows efforts...  And its about help not getting rep

Comment: I had asked this question just to know the opinion and suggestion but here I can see a lot of people are just thinking about the reputation part in my question and nothing other.And for those people I just want to say what is your purpose of giving answers to others questions.Don't you guys need reps.And I had given that much of time and effort in helping op to get his answer.So what is wrong if I am expecting some rewards for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me, based on this transcript: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/127278?m=33849686#33849686, that you were assisting another user with their question, namely this one: [Refresh ListView After SQLite update operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394839/refresh-listview-after-sqlite-update-operations)

I see your answer (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395036/1026459) to that question is the same solution that seemed to have been the reference from chat, and thus already exists. If you feel there is any extra information to include, then that answer should have that edited in so it is more relevant and more likely to receive an upvote in the future.

There is no reason to ask another question, and if the answer posted there helps other users in the future (or the OP of the question) then you will receive reputation.

One aspect to keep in mind is that while an individual answer may help one user, the overall goal is to write to both the OP, and to the general audience of the internet as they are the majority of views and votes at Stack Overflow.

Comment: No in the Chat we got the solution that is different from what I posted.

Comment: @AshishShukla - If that is the case then you should edit your answer, and leave a comment (since the OP has already commented on your answer) asking the OP if it is a correct solution so they may remove their deprecated comments or accept the solution you both came to.

Comment: This is the link to edit your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40395036/edit

Comment: Thanks Travis thats the answer I was expecting. Btw this is for the guys who just dont get inside the problem before giving negative votes , just  wait and watch what happened before reacting.

Comment: @AshishShukla That's good advice regardless and I fully support that plea, but in this case you can probably read the downvotes as people not agreeing with the way you approached it - from the perspective of deserving reputation rather than asking about what the correct course of action is.

Comment: I totally agree with you that I was not convincible with my question but yes sometimes people are not able to explain themselves at once.